# How to visualize values distributed on the line on its parallel (curves problem)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, visualisation, parallel-lines, parallel

I assign some value for each of points distributed equally on origin line, then I want to move this values to its paralllel line, by splitting those parallel line into equal pieces (which amount will be equal to amount of points)

Problem number 1 is that using v.parallel grass algorithm in places when turns are sharp, gives strange results (see green circle on picture). I know that this is probably good according to definition of [paralller curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_curve), but it is definetely not nice for visualization.

It could be ommited with doing buffer around this line and then cutting its ends. But then comes another problem. Inside sharp turns segments should be smaller and outside larger. In case when they are equal lenght then place of this segments on left and right parallel (which are generally different lenght) is different (see arrows on picture).

Imagine garden hose. If you bend it, then inside curve you will have material compressed, while outside material will be extended. I have to do the same in my case. Make more segments inside curve, and less outside. But how?

[image]
[image]